# Unable to get elevate.xml working with Apache Solr 1.4

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, solr

I’ve searched high and low for this via Google and the Solr wiki page, and cannot find the answer.

**My problem:**

I’m having trouble getting the elevate.xml working. I believe the problem is that I don’t know what the “doc id” is supposed to be within the elevate.xml. For example, if I search for “ice cream” I want it to return www.mydomain.com/page/2 as the first result.

```
    <query text="ice cream">
      <doc id="What Goes In Here??" />
    </query>
```

**What I’ve tried:**

I tried entering in that exact URL(example: www.mydomain.com/page/2), I’ve also searched for the page on http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/, which brings up the an XML response. I’ve taken the value from the “ID” child element (which is “9c3ec5/node/3564”) from this and tried it. 
Neither of these seem to work. I’ve also restarted the service after each change (this is running on a Windows 2008R2 Server as a service)

**Environment Info:**

Apache Solr 1.4.1 is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit). I’m searching using the Drupal Content Management System (version 6.22). Search is working great, except for this.

**Any Ideas?**

Does anyone have any ideas? Do I need to reindex the content?

Comment: More information: When I start Solr manually (java -Dsolr.solr.home=c:/solr/ -jar start.jar), I do see the elevate.xml is being loaded >> INFO: Loading QueryElevation from: c:\solr\conf\elevate.xml
Nov 10, 2011 11:11:24 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler inform
INFO: Adding  component:org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent@7bfbcffa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question and documented it at http://drupal.org/node/1338914

Comment: So what's the answer to this question, concretely?

Answer (score 0):

The "doc id" is the value of the [unique key](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field) of the document you want to elevate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How do I find the unique key (I did look at your URL)?

When I search /solr/admin/ for my search term, I do find the ID... I've tried using the value in <str name="id">9c3ec5/node/3564</str>, and it didn't work.

Comment: @mherchel : just changed the link to something more relevant.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. That being said, I think I'm doing it right (but its not working). Within the schema.xml, I have <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>. When I do a search at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/, I find the following in the returned XML: <str name="id">9c3ec5/node/3564</str>. So I plug that value into elevate.xml and restart the service, and it doesn't work. So, elevate.xml looks like  <query text="xxxx">
  <doc id="9c3ec5/node/3564" />
 </query>

Comment: Do I need to delete and re index the data?

Comment: @mherchel: that's weird... no, IIRC you don't need to reindex